# Change keyboard layout but keep shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard

I use three different keyboard layouts for three different languages on a regular basis and use a shortcut to cycle between them (this is very handy).

The one issue I regularly encounter is that many shortcuts change because the letter on the keyboard changes place, so the shortcut is the same, e.g., <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, but it's on a completely different position on the keyboard which makes the whole shorcut-thing not so short.

So is there a way to change the keyboard layout but keep the position of the keys used in shortcuts the same?